# Where to put public resources like JS, CSS and Images?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've been experimenting with where to put js/css files in my directory structure.  I think that it should go within the `WEB-INF` directory but that doesn't seem to work.  Putting them in `Web Pages` isn't working either.

Where do I put publicly visible resources like JS/CSS/Images ?

[image: Directory tree]

Comment: They should be in Web Pages outside of the WEB-INF directory. Why is that not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need to be at the root of your web context.

I don't know what Eclipse puts into your WAR file, but they should be in a path relative to its root.

Answer (score 0):

If the resources are in the WEB-INF directory they can not accessed directly, then you need some thing like a Resource Resolver.

```
<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

If the resources are outside the WEB-INF direcory, then they can be accessed directly, but you lose the ability to manipulate them.

Comment: Can you give an example situation on when I would want to manipulate them?